# Add an html element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple function to render the value of an input "text" into the html.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class='test'><input type='submit' value='send'>
</form>
<div class='test2'> </div>

<script>   
    $("form").submit(function() {
        var value = $('.test').val();
        $('.test2').html(value);
    });
</script>
```

The thing is that everytime we press "send", the new value replace the old one. I would like to display the new message without deleting the old ones, on top of them.
i.e I would like to add a 'DIV' or a 'P' each time I click on the button send.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, use id's instead of classes to uniquely identify elements.

Comment: Relevant jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Comment: Your code is so nice that a `<div>` is in between your `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var value = $('.test').val();
    $('.test2').append('<p>' + value + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `$('<p>', {text: $('.test').val()}).appendTo('.test2');`

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/azulux/4/edit)*

```
$("form").submit(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  $('<div>',{ text: $('.test').val() }).appendTo('.test2');
  $('form').get(0).reset();
});
```